# Google Earth plugin key not required, and not working either

Tags: google-earth, google-earth-plugin, api-key

The Google Earth browser plugin [apparently no longer requires a key](https://developers.google.com/maps/signup) and it's impossible to request one.

The problem is when I run [their sample code](http://owenmundy.com/teaching/code/apis/earth_no_key_test.php) (Chrome 18 and FireFox 10) [found here](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/index) I get an error message:

> The Google Maps API key used on this web site was registered for a different web site. The developer of this web site can generate a new key here.

When I check [their plugin page](http://www.google.com/earth/explore/products/plugin.html) it tells me:

> Good news, you already have the Google Earth Plug-in installed. (Version 6.0.3.2197)

So no key is required, but when I try to run the code sans key I'm told to get one, and I can't because Google has removed the ability to request one or download the update. I read online that 6.2 is the newest version but the key has not been required since 6.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying a force refresh, emptying the cache, and upgrading the browser, Google Chrome still wouldn't allow [my example that doesn't use a key](http://owenmundy.com/teaching/code/apis/earth_no_key_test.php) to work. I've figured out how to fix the issue.

The problem was that Chrome wasn't automatically updating the Google Earth browser plugin, regardless of the browser. Additionally, [their plugin page](http://www.google.com/earth/explore/products/plugin.html) confirmed I had an old version (6.0.3) but wouldn't allow me to manually update either. So I deinstalled the plugin following [these instructions](http://support.google.com/earth/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=178389), and then downloaded the newest version (6.2.2) and installed it. One final thing I had to do (on my MacBook Pro): the new plugin installed in Library in my user directory

```
~/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/
```

but to get it working correctly I had to move the "Google Earth Web Plug-in" file to the root's library and then restart Chrome.

```
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/
```

Answer (score 0):

The Earth API doesn't require a key - your sample code appears to be working properly. In case you do see an error message in the future, make sure that there's no `key=` parameter when loading the Google JS:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAAwbkbZLyhsmTCWXbTcjbgbRSzHs7K5SvaUdm8ua-Xxy_-2dYwMxQMhnagaawFo7L1FE1-amhuQxIlXw"></script>
```

The keys are specific to a domain, so if you copy old sample code from somewhere (such as from the [Demo Gallery](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/demogallery), for example) you should just strip out the `key=xxx` portion:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

Comment: Yep, I'm following that protocol but it still doesn't work for me in either of the browsers I mention above. What browser and version of the plugin are you using?

Comment: You may need to force a refresh on your page (http://superuser.com/questions/89809/how-to-force-refresh-without-cache-in-google-chrome). I tested your link in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox and it worked in all three.

Comment: I forced a refresh in Chrome (Command-Shift-R on Mac) and no luck. Could you tell me what version of the plugin you have?

Answer (score 0):

Despite it saying you don´t need an API key for Google Earth at various official places, your problem is solved, if you create one on https://code.google.com/apis/console (under "API access" and then click on "Create new browser key") and include in the jsapi include: `<script src="//www.google.com/jsapi?key=yourkeyhere" type="text/javascript"></script>`